# Resample non timed df with a groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, mean

I'd like to get the weighted average by meter of 'grade' in my df.
I have to use a groupby 'name' and 'grade' is the column I try to get the mean values.
'From' and 'to' are the vertical boundaries where 'grade' is applied.

Example :

input :

```
name   from   to   grade
 -       -     -     -
 A       0    1.5   1.0
 A      1.5   3.0   1.5
 A      3.0    4    1.7 
 B       0     3    1.6
 B       3    3.7   1.9
 B      3.7    5    2.0
```

desired output :

```
name   from   to    grade
 -       -     -      -
 A       0     1     1.0 
 A       1     2     1.25
 A       2     3     1.5
 A       3     4     1.7
 B       0     1     1.6
 B       1     2     1.6
 B       2     3     1.6
 B       3     4     1.93 (=1.9 x 0.7 + 2.0 x 0.3)
 B       4     5     2.0
```

I'm working with pandas and tried a "rolling_mean" but it didn't worked out well.

Any ideas ?

EDIT :
Thanks EBDS for your time and for your answer, I tried your code and here is some more details :

1. from my understanding of this part of your code :

> ```
> else:
>   grade = r1['ni']*(r1['to'] - i) + r2['ni']*(to_val - r1['to'] )
>   row = [{'holeid': r1['holeid'],'from': i,'to': i+1,'ni': grade}]
> ```

only 2 values are taken for the weighted average, but there can be up to 10 values in 1 meter (but again it's only my understanding, please confirm). example:
input :

```
name   from    to    grade
  -      -      -      -
  A     0.0   1.8     0.5
  A     1.8   2.15    1.0
  A     2.15  2.21    1.4
  A     2.21  2.5     1.6
  A     2.5   2.9     1.7
  A     2.9   3.2     1.0
```

desired output:

```
name   from    to    grade
  -      -      -      -
  A     0      1.0    0.5
  A     1.0    2.0    0.6 (0.8 x 0.5 + 0.2 x 1.0)
  A     2.0    3.0    1.478 (0.15x1.0+0.06x1.4+0.29x1.6+0.4x1.7+0.1x1.0)
  A     3.0    4.0    1.0
```

2. I tried it with my full dataset and the last long samples are often undivided (as follow) :

[image: append rows when if thickness (depth_to-depth_from) > 1 when there is no remaining samples behind]

EDIT2 : behavior of first 'from' and last 'to'
more details of the logic where 5.6 is the 1st from and 7.9 the last to

input :

```
name  from   to    grade
 -      -     -      -
 A     5.6   5.7    1.4
 A     5.7   5.9    1.0
 A     5.9   6.2    1.3
 A     6.2   6.9    1.6
 A     6.9   7.1    1.7
 A     7.1   7.6    1.0
 A     7.6   7.9    1.9
```

desired output :

```
name    from  to    grade
  -      -     -      -
  A     5.6   6.0   1.175 ((0.1x1.4 + 0.2x1.0 + 0.1x1.3)/0.4) 
  A     6.0   7.0   1.55 ((0.2x1.3 + 0.7x1.6 + 0.1x1.7)/1) 
  A     7.0   7.9   1.378 ((0.1x1.7 + 0.5x1.0 + 0.3x1.9)/0.9)
```

Comment: Hi, are you meaning that you wants `weighted average` from your columns `from` and `to` ?

Comment: I've produced a possible solution below.  If that's what you want, kindly accept the  answer by checking it.  Thanks.

Comment: Wow ! that was more complicated than I thought, thanks a lot! I try it and come back checking if it works.

Comment: I dont' understand your calculation.  for  (0.8 x 0.5 + 0.2 x 1.0), it doesn't have fractional from and to, why do you need to calculate ?  I also don't understand how you get this (0.15x1.0+0.06x1.4+0.29x1.6+0.4x1.7+0.1x1.0) calculation ?  Your question is very interesting though.  Anyway to understand the question better ?

Comment: in the lenght from 1.0 to 2.0 there will be 0.8m of 0.5 % grade from the 0-1.8 row and 0.2m of 1.0% grade from the 1.8 - 2.15 row.

Comment: And then in the 2.0 to 3.0 output there will be : 0.15m of 1.0% grade from the 1.8 - 2.15 row ; 0.06m of 1.4% grade from the 2.15 - 2.21 row ; ... ; and 0.1m of 1.0% from the 2.9 - 3.2m row

Comment: Do you know how I can proceed ? There is no limitation on how it should be computed

Comment: Give me a bit of time to think about it as I need to finish up somethings now.  How urgent is this.  I'm very interested to solve this.  I'm think of manipulating the Pandas Dataframe rather than using coding.  Is there a way I can reach you cause the msg format here is a bit difficult to see what you want and I can't seem to use chat on Stack Overflow.

Comment: let me know if you find something, I will try to dig it too

Comment: Will your first "from" and last "to" be a fraction ?  If a fraction, how to handle ?

Comment: Yes the last 'to' can be a fraction but I can merge the initial df.groupby('name')['to'].max() and replace that last 'to' after the loop :)

Comment: The first 'from' will always be zero but if it can work with a fraction it's better

Comment: may be if we can first append a row any time we cross an integer, it may be easier to work with ?

Comment: ok.. then do you want to handle the last 'to' as fraction for this purpose or you assumed it's a whole number ?  If fraction, what is the logic to handle ?  Cause there are no more values are it to calculate the last 'to'.  And if you want to have fraction for first 'from', what is the logic ?  Or if it's always zero, should just leave it that way ?

Comment: Let me know how to handle the first 'from' and last 'to' if it's not a whole number.  I'll think about how to solve this over the weekend.

Comment: thanks so much for helping me out !! I updated the main topic under 'EDIT2'

Comment: @VncJ Something new /0.4, /0.9.. am I right to say that you divide by 0.4 and 0.9 is applicable only for non-whole number first "from" and last "to" ?  the rest are divide by '1" and thus can be ignore.  Cause in all the previous examples given, there were no divide required and I suspect is because it's divide by "1".   seems like we have a 12 hour time difference... I'm in +8 GMT.  It's always a 1 day turn around. ;-)

Comment: you're absolutely right

Comment: You previously said that the first "to" is always whole number 0 ?  Is that correct ?  If it is, I suggest, the algo not handle a fraction.  Is that ok ?  The algo becomes more complicated and possible bugs will occur.

Comment: The first 'from' is always 0, I just was looking forward to another application for a fraction on the first "from". But if the code works with 1st from = 0 then it's ok :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is not pretty.  It's working as it is.  I hope there is a better way to code this.  It's not a single step logic that I can explain on this editor.  Best is to use an IDE to step through.  You have to touch up for your website.  Some of these things like I print 'bug', just edit out.  Some for testing purpose.  Good luck to your website !

```
from io import StringIO
from math import floor,ceil
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity='all'

df = pd.read_excel('Resample non timed df with a groupby (VNC J).xlsx',sheet_name='NW04',dtype={'from':np.float64,'to':np.float64}) \
        .rename(columns={'from':'from1','to':'to1'}).reindex()
df['from2'] = df['from1'].apply(floor)
df['to2'] = df['to1'].apply(floor)
df

    name    from1   to1 grade   from2   to2
0   A   0.00    3.10    7.36    0   3
1   A   3.10    3.20    5.18    3   3
2   A   3.20    3.30    7.45    3   3
3   A   3.30    3.60    8.91    3   3
4   A   3.60    4.00    7.82    3   4
5   B   4.00    5.00    8.00    4   5
6   C   5.00    6.00    8.18    5   6
7   D   6.00    7.10    7.09    6   7
8   E   7.10    7.90    6.55    7   7
9   E   7.90    8.10    9.09    7   8
10  F   8.10    12.50   1.09    8   12
11  G   12.50   15.00   7.09    12  15
12  H   15.00   15.01   3.45    15  15
13  I   15.01   15.10   13.00   15  15

df1 = df.copy(deep=True)

lst = []
accum = 0
multi_row_to = -1
multi_row_last = 0

for r in range(len(df)):
    name = df.loc[r, 'name']
    from1 = df.loc[r, 'from1']
    to1 = df.loc[r, 'to1']
    from2 = df.loc[r, 'from2']
    to2 = df.loc[r, 'to2']
    grade = df.loc[r, 'grade']
    to_span = to2 - from2

    if ((multi_row_to != -1) and (to2 != multi_row_last)):
        multi_row_to = -1

    if (r == len(df)-1) and (floor(from2)==floor(to2)):  #  last row with small from/to
        multi_row_to = -1
        grade_out = ((to1 - from1) * grade + accum) / (to1 - floor(to1))
        accum = 0
        lst.append((name, r, from1, to1, grade, from2, to1, grade_out, accum))
    elif ((to1 % 1) == 0) and (to_span < 2):  # no multi-rows (wrong to1 == to2)
        multi_row_to = -1
        grade_out = (to2 - from1) * grade + accum
        accum = (to1 - to2) * grade
        lst.append((name, r, from1, to1, grade, from2, to2, grade_out, accum))
    elif to1 != to2 and to_span < 2:  # continue multi-rows
        if multi_row_to == to2:
            if to2 > from2:
                multi_row_to = to2 # (next value)
                grade_out = (to2 - from1) * grade + accum
                accum = (to1 - to2) * grade
                lst.append((name, r, from1, to1, grade, from2, to2, grade_out, accum))
            else:
                grade_out = '-'
                accum += (to1 - from1) * grade
                lst.append((name, r, from1, to1, grade, from2, to2, grade_out, accum))
        elif multi_row_to == -1: # entered multi_row
            multi_row_last = to2
            if to2 > from2:
                multi_row_to = to2 # (next value)
                grade_out = (to2 - from1) * grade + accum
                accum = (to1 - to2) * grade
                lst.append((name, r, from1, to1, grade, from2, to2, grade_out, accum))
            else:
                multi_row_to = to2
                grade_out = '-'
                accum += (to1 - from1) * grade ### Changed here bug
                lst.append((name, r, from1, to1, grade, from2, to2, grade_out, accum))
        else: # switch number in multi_row

            multi_row_to = to2
            grade_out = (to2 - from1) * grade + accum
            accum = (to1 - to2) * grade
            lst.append((name, r, from1, to1, grade, from2, to2, grade_out, accum))
    elif to_span >= 2:  # explod grade
        explode_first = True
        for i in range(from2, to2+1):
            if explode_first:  # i == from1:  # first
                explode_first = False
                grade_out = (i + 1 - from1) * grade + accum
                accum = 0
                lst.append((name, r, from1, to1, grade, i, i + 1, grade_out, accum))
            elif ((i == to2) and (floor(to1) != to1)):  # last decimal
                grade_out = '-'
                accum = (to1 - to2) * grade  # changed here
                lst.append((name, r, from1, to1, grade, i, to1, grade_out, accum))
                # if accum != 0:
                #     grade_out = accum
                #     accum = 0
                #     lst.append((name, r + 1, '-', '-', '-', to2, to1, grade_out, accum))
            elif ((i == (to2-1)) and (floor(to1) == to1)) : # whole number
                grade_out = grade
                accum = (to2 - to1) * grade
                lst.append((name, r, from1, to1, grade, i, i + 1, grade_out, accum))
                break   #  no choice, cater to last number decimal
            else:  # middle
                if accum != 0:
                    grade_out = (i + 1 - from1) * grade + accum
                    accum = 0
                    lst.append((name, r, from1, to1, grade, i, i + 1, grade_out, accum))
                elif (i + 1) <= to1:
                    grade_out = grade
                    accum = 0  # redundant but leave it
                    lst.append((name, r, from1, to1, grade, i, i + 1, grade_out, accum))
                # elif (i + 1) > to1:
                #     grade_out = (to1 - from2) * grade
                #     accum = 0
                #     lst.append((name, r, from1, to1, grade, i, to1, grade_out, accum))
                else:
                    print('Bug 1')
    else:
        print('Bug 2')
        break

if accum != 0:
    grade_out = accum / (to1-to2)
    accum = 0
    lst.append((name, r + 1, '-', '-', '-', to2, to1, grade_out, accum))


col = ['name', 'r', 'from1', 'to1', 'grade', 'from2', 'to2', 'grade_out', 'accum']
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in lst:
    df2 = df2.append(pd.DataFrame(i).T)
df2.columns = col
df2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df2

    name    r   from1   to1 grade   from2   to2 grade_out   accum
0   A   0   0.0 3.1 7.36    0   1   7.36    0
1   A   0   0.0 3.1 7.36    1   2   7.36    0
2   A   0   0.0 3.1 7.36    2   3   7.36    0
3   A   0   0.0 3.1 7.36    3   3.1 -   0.736
4   A   1   3.1 3.2 5.18    3   3   -   1.254
5   A   2   3.2 3.3 7.45    3   3   -   1.999
6   A   3   3.3 3.6 8.91    3   3   -   4.672
7   A   4   3.6 4.0 7.82    3   4   7.8 0.0
8   B   5   4.0 5.0 8.0 4   5   8.0 0.0
9   C   6   5.0 6.0 8.18    5   6   8.18    0.0
10  D   7   6.0 7.1 7.09    6   7   7.09    0.709
11  E   8   7.1 7.9 6.55    7   7   -   5.949
12  E   9   7.9 8.1 9.09    7   8   6.858   0.909
13  F   10  8.1 12.5    1.09    8   9   1.89    0
14  F   10  8.1 12.5    1.09    9   10  1.09    0
15  F   10  8.1 12.5    1.09    10  11  1.09    0
16  F   10  8.1 12.5    1.09    11  12  1.09    0
17  F   10  8.1 12.5    1.09    12  12.5    -   0.545
18  G   11  12.5    15.0    7.09    12  13  4.09    0
19  G   11  12.5    15.0    7.09    13  14  7.09    0
20  G   11  12.5    15.0    7.09    14  15  7.09    0.0
21  H   12  15.0    15.01   3.45    15  15  -   0.0345
22  I   13  15.01   15.1    13.0    15  15.1    12.045  0

df3 = pd.DataFrame()
newto = -1 # df2.loc[0,'to2']

for i in range(len(df2)):
#     if df2.loc[i,'to2'] != newto:
    if df2.loc[i,'grade_out'] != '-':
        df3 = df3.append(df2.loc[i,:])
        newto = df2.loc[i,'to2']
        
df3.drop(columns=['r','accum'],inplace=True)
df3

    name    from1   to1 grade   from2   to2 grade_out
0   A   0.00    3.1 7.36    0.0 1.0 7.360
1   A   0.00    3.1 7.36    1.0 2.0 7.360
2   A   0.00    3.1 7.36    2.0 3.0 7.360
7   A   3.60    4.0 7.82    3.0 4.0 7.800
8   B   4.00    5.0 8.00    4.0 5.0 8.000
9   C   5.00    6.0 8.18    5.0 6.0 8.180
10  D   6.00    7.1 7.09    6.0 7.0 7.090
12  E   7.90    8.1 9.09    7.0 8.0 6.858
13  F   8.10    12.5    1.09    8.0 9.0 1.890
14  F   8.10    12.5    1.09    9.0 10.0    1.090
15  F   8.10    12.5    1.09    10.0    11.0    1.090
16  F   8.10    12.5    1.09    11.0    12.0    1.090
18  G   12.50   15.0    7.09    12.0    13.0    4.090
19  G   12.50   15.0    7.09    13.0    14.0    7.090
20  G   12.50   15.0    7.09    14.0    15.0    7.090
22  I   15.01   15.1    13.00   15.0    15.1    12.045
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Kindly accept the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Hey EBDS, I've accepted. I've found a smoother and easier way to accomplish it, I will share later. 1) Resample to append rows every time from cross an integer 2) use a double groupby name and step_from with a mean

Answer (score 1):

This code is very raw.  I just got it to work.  You can try it on your full set of data and see if that's what you want.  Then can touch up the codes.
I don't know how to manipulate it the pandas way. I only know the programmatic loop/ifelse way.  May be somebody could give you something more elegant.  If not, you can use

```
def cal_grade(df):
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['name','from','to','grade'])
    for r in range(len(df)-1):
        r1 = df.iloc[r,:]
        r2 = df.iloc[r+1,:]
        from_val = math.ceil(r1['from'])
        to_val = math.ceil(r1['to'])
        if to_val == (r1['to']):
            for i in range(from_val,to_val):
                row = [{'name': r1['name'],'from':i,'to': i+1,'grade': r1['grade']}]
                df1 = df1.append(row,ignore_index=True)
        else:
            for i in range(from_val,to_val):
                if i < to_val-1:
                    row = [{'name': r1['name'],'from': i,'to': i+1,'grade': r1['grade']}]
                else:
                    grade = r1['grade']*(r1['to'] - i) + r2['grade']*(to_val - r1['to'] )
                    row = [{'name': r1['name'],'from': i,'to': i+1,'grade': grade}]
                df1 = df1.append(row,ignore_index=True)
    df1 = df1.append(df.iloc[-1,:],ignore_index=True)
    from_val = df1['from'].iloc[-1]
    from_val1 = math.ceil(from_val)
    df1.replace(from_val,from_val1,inplace=True)
    return df1
df
df.groupby('name').apply(cal_grade).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output

```
    name    from    to      grade
0   A       0.0     1.5     1.0
1   A       1.5     3.0     1.5
2   A       3.0     4.0     1.7
3   B       0.0     3.0     1.6
4   B       3.0     3.7     1.9
5   B       3.7     5.0     2.0
6   B       5.0     8.3     5.0
7   B       8.3     10.5    8.0
8   B       10.5    14.0    10.0

    name    from    to      grade
0   A       0       1.0     1.00
1   A       1       2.0     1.25
2   A       2       3.0     1.50
3   A       3       4.0     1.70
4   B       0       1.0     1.60
5   B       1       2.0     1.60
6   B       2       3.0     1.60
7   B       3       4.0     1.93
8   B       4       5.0     2.00
9   B       5       6.0     5.00
10  B       6       7.0     5.00
11  B       7       8.0     5.00
12  B       8       9.0     7.10
13  B       9       10.0    8.00
14  B       10      11.0    9.00
15  B       11      14.0    10.00
```

I've added some more rows to test it.  Some of those variable used can be cleaned up but you just see if this is what you want first.

Comment: Thanks ! I have a question, does this code works with more than 2 grade values ?
I can have up to 10 values between 1 meter of depth from / depth to like :
`name      from     to      grade
   A             0        0.1      1.5
   A            0.1      0.5       2.0
   A            0.5      0.6       1.0
   A            0.6      1.0       1.4`

Comment: (sorry for the poor formatting, I cant even edit now, but basically like 10 values between 1 meter of from and to)

Comment: Also it can be cut anywhere, ex : from = 0.95, to = 1.2

Comment: Another thing : for example if I have a row with from = 5 and a to = 8, the output should have 3 rows append

Comment: 1. I've tested with (5,8,3) and it's able to "expand" to multiple rows. 
2. Your initial question data shows the output data boundary of 1 unit, ie the output is (1,2), (2,3),(3,4),(4,5).... so the looping logic splits the data into units of 1 (as in your sample output).  The data you provided later in the comment is sub-one, ie several input row with boundaries smaller than 1.  So what is the expected output ?  Without the expected output, it's not possible to know whether it can be done or not.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I edited my initial question to add more details

Comment: That was my worry when I coded the loop.  That there were other requirements.  The loop is dependent on the next value as given in the original data.  In the new case, need a finer loop if going to build using the current logic.  Perhaps, there are better ways to control it using pandas groupby (creating a new column with floor varriables and groupby that variable) or other methods.  It's going to take time, have to think about it.  This is a real app you're coding ?  For educational institution ?  It's an interesting question.

Comment: Yes, I'm building a web app for our University that we would test with our students with field data. I tried to implement more r (r3, r4, ..., r10) and tried to add if in the loop but resulted in an IndexError warning...